# OnTouchEvent Issue Android

Tags: android, touch-event

I'm getting frustated with OnTouchEvent. I wanna detect only 5 fingers.How can I achieve that? Also the problem is that it calls multiple times. Here is my code :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

    System.out.println("My pointer....." + pointerCount);

    final int action = event.getAction();

       if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

           if(pointerCount >= 4){


           Log.d("MyActivity", "in onTouchEvent!");
          Toast.makeText(MyclassActivity.this, "Finger !!"+pointerCount,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             Intent z = new Intent(MyclassActivity.this,
                        DashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(z);
            finish();
           }      

    }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

I am not satisfied with this thing. let me take your help to get and count exact 5 fingers and avoid multiple times calling of onTouchevent.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you don't understand what is touch event. This is not click on screen. If you move any finger or change pressure `onTouchEvent` will be called.

Comment: The onTouch method is designed to be called whenever there is an action on the screen, so you can't avoid multiple calls. Why aren't you satisfied here ?

Comment: Try this link
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: @PlumillonForge : I'm not satisfied because I wanna execute my stuff inside if I can get pointercount 4 or more. Otherwise It will call mutiple times.

Comment: @abc667 : I know brother. That is my question how can I avoid multiple times calling if I wanna touch and wanna detect 5 fingers only!!

Comment: @ShreeshaS : I have checked that! But may be its confusing code. can you help me with that?

Comment: Are Monty ...ACTION_POINTER_UP lga ke dekh....ACTION_up ki jagah

Comment: @gaurav Kumawat :Done bhai given below code kam kr rha h after some changes..thanks for advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP` is being called every time you remove a single finger from your screen. So if you touch your screen with 5 fingers it will turn true more than 1 time. Try using `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` in your implementation. Count all the fingers -> check when `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is called -> do you code only if the highest amount of fingers was 5.

```
int maxPointercount; 
int previousPointercount; 

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 

     int currentpointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

     Log.d("1", "My pointer = " + currentpointerCount); //what does it say here?

     final int action = event.getAction();
          switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
               case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:          
                 if(maxPointercount <= previousPointercount){
                 maxPointercount = currentpointerCount;
                }
                previousPointercount = currentpointerCount;
          }  

    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       Log.d("3", maxPointercount + " = maxPointercount");
       if(maxPointercount == 5){ //or whatever amount of fingers, try it out. 

          //your code that will run 1 time

       }
          maxPointercount = 0;
          previousPointercount = 0;      

     }
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Edit: Fixed it again! Now it really works.

Comment: I have used that!! But then it is not able to get pointercount!! It will work if I will touch only 1 finger also!!

Comment: As you said I have updated my code here!! It's not working!! See above code and let me take your help!!

Comment: You will have to do more then just replace that single line of code brother! ACTION_UP is sent when the last finger leaves the screen, at that point you need to know what the highest amount of fingers was during the time you touched the screen and released all the fingers. If it is 5, run your code.

Comment: ACTION_POINTER_DOWN is for extra fingers that enter the screen beyond the FIRST. So it's supposed to be 4 then I guess.

Comment: I have put 4,3,2... but it is not satisfying that condition!!

Comment: You didn't put "int maxPointercount" and "int previousPointercount;" inside the onTouch() right? They need to be global variables.  What does the print line say before the condition? Please edit your orignal post instead of commenting here.

Comment: Yup I have put it both variables globally!!

Comment: I have tried to print both values in logcat. After touched screen, each time both variables are giving value "0"

Comment: Ok I found the problem and tested it myself to make sure it was correct.

Comment: Have you tried my latest code? I updated it yesterday. Is has an ACTION_MASK switch and some other new things. It worked on my Tablet.

Answer (score 1):

i got lots of trouble knowing how does it work, so here is the basic things i came up with

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    int eventaction = event.getAction();
    String str= "";
    //touch Events, i came up with the mask 5 by trial, hope it works for all devices
    //eventaction == 0 match the first touch event ever
    if( ( eventaction & 5 ) == 5  || eventaction == 0 ){
        str= "Touch Event";
    }
    //Release Event, i came up with the mask 6 by trial, hope it works for all devices 
    //eventaction == 1 match the last release event ever, this makes it hard to know wich finger was removed 
    if( ( eventaction & 6 ) == 6  || eventaction == 1 ){
        str= "Release Event:";
    }
    if( eventaction == 2 ){
        str= "Move Event:";
        return true;//it will make a mess in the logcat, if u want remove this line
    }
    str += " With Number Of fingers " + event.getPointerCount() ;
    str += ", the finger triggered the event is : finger ";
    //some stupid thing i have done, but it works 
    //these numbers was made based on the binary mask that i was able to figure out
    //but it still has an issue with the last finger removed as its eventaction  is always 0, but this can be pragmatically known by monitoring each finger touch and release 
    switch ( eventaction ){
    case 0:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        str += "1";
        break;
    case 261:
    case 262:
        str += "2";
        break;
    case 517:
    case 518:
        str += "3";
        break;
    case 773:
    case 774:
        str += "4";
        break;
    case 1029:
    case 1030:
        str += "5";
        break;
    case 1285:
    case 1286:
        str += "6";
        break;
    case 1541:
    case 1542:
        str += "7";
        break;
    case 1797:
    case 1798:
        str += "8";
        break;
    case 2053:
    case 2054:
        str += "9";
        break;
    case 2309:
    case 2310:
        str += "10";
        break;
    }
    Log.d("Test", str );
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps anybody, if you still have missing info then i will be glad to help ^_^.